# NodeMCU hc05 Connection

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu, hc-05

I am using a NodeMCU from Amica. I tried interfacing the HC-05 module to the NodeMCU.

The following code works fine without any errors

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial btport(D2, D3);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(38400);
  btport.begin(38400);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()){
    btport.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if(btport.available()){
    Serial.write(btport.read());
  }
}
```

But when I change the code to the following the serial monitor displays garbage values.

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial btport(D2, D3);


int count = 0;
char data[200];
char c;
int flag = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(74880);
  btport.begin(38400);
}

void clearData(){
  int i = 0;
  while(i < 200){
    data[i] = '\0';
    //yield();
  }
  count = 0;
}

void loop() {
  clearData();
  btport.write("AT+INQ\r\n");
  delay(200);
  if(btport.available()){
    while(btport.available()){
      c = btport.read();
      data[count++] = c;
      data[count] = '\0';
    }
  }
  Serial.println(data);
}
```

The output of the above code is

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1392, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0xd0
csum 0xd0
v3d128e5c
~ld

Soft WDT reset

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffe00 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 01b0
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe84e4 40101289  
<<<stack<<<
¢„*«P*V¡¡ET©«´¥T«ª«*¥u´U+UZªªUT¢üªTQT¥UQ©©jPªV©µuª¥…¢üZT¥(EŠª«ªQTEªj*QTE«ªUUªŠø/¥Å
Soft WDT reset

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffe00 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 01b0
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe84e4 40101289  
<<<stack<<<
¢„*«P*V¡¡ET©«´¥T«ª«*¥u´U+UZªªUT¢üªTQT¥UQ©©jPªV©µuª¥…¢üZT¥(EŠª«ªQTEªj*QTE«ªUUªŠø/¥Å
```

What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: did you change the speed of the serial monitor as well?

Comment: @dandavis Yeah. I tried with different speeds. But didn't work.